# How to select html based file uploader's (input type="file") file as asp:net FileUpload in web forms?

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms

I have two file upload on my page:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
     <input type="file" id="FileDialog" name="FileDialog" />
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and another file uploader is

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileDialogMC" runat="server" CssClass="col" OnLoad="Page_Load" accept=".docx, .pdf" required="true" Enabled="false" />
```

I can access the files for asp:FileUpload by this code:

```
if (FileDialogMC.HasFile)
            {
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(FileDialogMC.PostedFile.FileName);
                Attachment attachment = new Attachment(FileDialogMC.PostedFile.InputStream, fi.Name);
                attachment.ContentType.MediaType = FileDialogMC.PostedFile.ContentType;
                message.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            }
```

How do I write code something like above one for `<input type="file" id="FileDialog" name="FileDialog" />`

Answer (score 0):

For file upload using HTML file upload control, you need to use ajax call and handler file required for logic.

Please refer to [this link](https://codepedia.info/upload-image-using-jquery-ajax-asp-net-c-sharp)